# Basic server and Client interaction- Java

Tags: java

Good day,

The code below runs but the server only writes the string after i terminate it or the client only receives the string i sent after i terminate the running server.
What should happen is upon connection the client sends a hello message to the server which the server reads and outputs to the console then server writes a message back to client then client reads the message and outputs it to console before disconnecting promptly.

```
    public class Server 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    ServerSocket ss;
    try {
    ss=new ServerSocket(2018);
    Socket s=ss.accept();
    System.out.println("connected...");
    Handler h =new Handler(s);
    Thread t=new Thread(h);
    t.start();
    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }

//client handler.

    public Handler(Socket s) 
        {
            cs=s;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {

            try 
            {
            pw=new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream());
            sc=new Scanner(cs.getInputStream());
            pw.write("SERVER SAYS:Hello");
            pw.flush();
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        //then the client.

         public class Client {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Socket s;
            PrintWriter pw;
            Scanner sc;

            try {
            s=new Socket("localhost",2018);
            pw=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            sc=new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
            pw.write("HELLO");
            pw.flush();
            String msg=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(msg);
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is good and valid, but please edit your code to be a [MCVE] (right now this code doesn't compile, your Handler class isn't complete and both the Client and Server class are missing closing brackets. Please also format the code properly, it's really difficult to read in its current state. Thanks!

Comment: And please edit your title to more directly address your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your client calls `sc.nextLine()`, which will block until a newline character is in the stream or until the connection is closed. Since your server never sends a newline character (`\n`), `sc.nextLine()` only returns once you terminate the server.

Change `pw.write("SERVER SAYS:Hello");` to `pw.write("SERVER SAYS:Hello\n");` and it will work as expected.

Comment: thank you.apologies for the structure of my question.